# Kernel compilation error (invalid magic number)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, fedora

I am trying to compile the kernel from downloaded source. I made the kernel image using sources from kernel.org.

I have successfully loaded it into grub, but when I try to run the loaded module it gives error message: `"invalid magic number"`. I am not getting what I need to fix to get the things done.

Steps that I've followed:

1. make xconfig,
2. make bzImage
3. make modules
4. make modules_install
5. I also changed the name of image from bzImage (in /boot folder), then created initrd image from:
6. `# dracut /boot/initramfs-3.1.6-1.fc16.x86_64.img 3.1.6-1.fc16.x86_64` (command copied from net)

Answer (score 3):

Every time you compile a kernel, you must re-compile also the kernel module that you need to use within that kernel. For example, you cannot load a module compiled for kernel 2.6.39 on kernel 3.7. You must recompile it for kernel 3.7.

More details --> better answer

Comment: I made module with the command "make modules",then "make modules_install"

Comment: And I suppose that you got the same error. Can you post the exact error message? Are you loading the correct kernel?

Comment: I am getting : Loading intial ram disk ,error : load kernel first

Comment: It look like a different problem

Answer (score 2):

Actually I doubt this has anything to do with kernel modules. As it seems the kernel itself is being refered to as a module. It is possible the kernel got built incorrectly or is being loaded incorrectly possibly from the grub commandline.

http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-932358-start-0.html try that.

It is possible that some file in the kernel build didn't get cleaned up properly an so has incorrect data in it since any changes you made in a previous attempt at building it.

Also do note that the x86 images will end up at arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage or arch/x86/boot/bzImage inside the kernel source make sure you actually have copied the kernel itself and not some other incorrect file.

If that fails try grub 1.x as its simpler to use than grub 2.x just note that alot of things are different and you should read tutorials for the correct version of grub. Often grub 1.x will be in a grub-legacy or similar package depending on the distro.

Edit: If you are building your kernel for your hardware only... do not use an initramfs its overkill. There are places you would want to do this is if your system is incapable of loading a kernel large enough for essential drivers (sparc for instance is very limited in kernel image size). another being booting over network possibly but by and large it isn't needed. If you *must* use an initramfs get your kernel build working without it first.

Also personally I build my kernel with essential drivers included (disk and filesystem basically) and build it with.

```
make mrproper (save/backup your .config first) ; 
make menuconfig ; 
make -j8 ; 
make modules_install ; 
cp arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /boot/linux-3.7.1 ;
```

(modify grub to boot the new kernel) and im done and ready to reboot.

Any chance you could attach a screenshot of the failure?

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Glad to have the steps you use to compile and install the new kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting your question 100% clearly. Anyway, you downloaded some kernel tree from kernel.org and successfully booted with new Image.

Then you are trying to load a LKM i.e kernel module using insmod or modprobe.

so you are getting "Invalid magic number".

**Solution**

Need to re-compile the kernel module in new kernel, then try to insert.